# Accessing a Numpy Matrix from C as a 3D array

Tags: python, c, arrays, numpy, 3d

I have noticed that it is possible to create a borrowed/stolen reference to a (3D) numpy array of floats using `PyArray_AsCArray` as following:

```
...
float ***matrix_c;
npy_intp dims[3] = {X, Y, Z};
PyArray_Descr *descriptor = PyArray_DescrFromType(NPY_FLOAT32);
PyArray_AsCArray(&matrix_pyobject, (void **)&matrix_c, dims, 3, descriptor);
...
```

However, when doing this from different parts in the code with the intention of transferring the same array, this will not work for my case. I needed each of the transfers to give me a reference to the inner array, so I could work with the same addresses.

For this purpose I found out I could access the internal array without worrying about references using `PyArray_DATA`, nonetheless this gives a 1D flat view of the matrix as a `void *` referencing the first element of the matrix.

Is there any way in which I can get a reference to the internal array using this last call and still be able to work with the array as a 3D C array?

Comment: Is there a reason why you aren't using a 3D array in C, if that's what you actually need?

Comment: The array I obtain comes from the Python-side of an application. I transfer a 3D Numpy array for heavy computation phases to C, access and modify it in C, and then continue the Python-part with the now-modified Numpy array. All this, without transferring data or making copies (thus why I need direct references)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15576136/passing-3-dimensional-numpy-array-to-c

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51036850/get-pointer-from-numpy-array-to-send-image-to-c

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14341549/passing-a-set-of-numpy-arrays-into-c-function-for-input-and-output

Comment: The first link uses borrowed references, which I want to avoid as I specified above. The third one uses ctypes, which I also want to avoid as I believe it should be possible to have python-floats + C-floats interactions without the need for an extra package from the python-side (I already use numpy for other things in the python-side). As for the second URL I believe this is what NumPy inherently uses, so this should be exposed somehow within the calls I mentioned above (correct me if I'm wrong, as I'm no expert in the internals of the NumPy-C API).

Comment: Wow... Python actually uses 3 star programming as back end, or is this numpy thing just yet another horrid open source lib? And then people wonder why Python is slow...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found out quite an easy way to solve this, so I will post it just in case anyone else struggles with this.

I tried solving it through a pointer of 2D structures, but in the end, all which I needed was a cast to a pointer to 3D structures:

```
PyObject *matrix_object;
PyArg_ParseTuple(args, "O", &matrix_object);
float *matrix_c = (float *)PyArray_DATA((PyArrayObject *)matrix_object);
npy_intp *shape = PyArray_DIMS((PyArrayObject *)matrix_object);

// More code...
int numblocks = shape[0];
int blocksize = shape[1];
int elemsize  = shape[2];

float (*structured_matrix)[numblocks][blocksize][elemsize] = (float (*)[numblocks][blocksize][elemsize])matrix_c;

// Access structured_matrix as: structured_matrix[X][Y][Z]
```